# org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, liferay

I try to run a spring project using `LocalSessionFactory`, I get a null pointer 'cause I've to init the classLoader. Any way I got this exception at the end!

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactoryClassLoader' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'sessionFactoryClassLoader' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.`

Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

any suggestions?

Here is the implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
 <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Database" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />

 </bean>


 <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource"></property>
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:META-INF/products.xml
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="sessionFactoryClassLoader" ref="portletClassLoader" />
    </bean>

 <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

 <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
        <bean id="portletClassLoader" class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletClassLoaderUtil" factory-method="getClassLoader" />
    </beans>
```

by the way I want to replace com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletClassLoaderUtil by another classLoader using springFramework or hibernate Libraries!

Comment: This exception is pretty clear. Spring is tryng to set sessionFactoryClassLoader with a setSessionFactoryClassLoader(..) method that not exists into org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean class. Post your configuration please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sessionFactoryClassLoader is not a property of org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.
It is available for PortletSessionFactory implementation which extends [SessionFactoryImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-impl/6.1.0/com/liferay/portal/dao/orm/hibernate/SessionFactoryImpl.java#SessionFactoryImpl.wrapSession%28org.hibernate.Session%29).

Comment: there is no way to set classLoader and keep using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean?

Comment: @user3429578 You can try with beanClassLoader property. Check here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setBeanClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29